# OpenGL strange issue : Screen fit on 480x854 device, crop image having 1 px diff, what's up?

Tags: android, opengl-es, screen

I am work my game on android, using OpenGL developing 2D game, running on 320x480 device was work.(no any broken)

Unfortunately issue on my motorola defy (480x854), seems like the adjust UV point object having 1-px diff(up or down 1 px position deviation).

SurfaceChanged return width 320,height 569
AndroidManifest anyDensity is setting false

Below two images have two rectangle, the left one is original image(w=36,h=35), no crop; middle one is clip by uv, draw from px1 and crop only width 34px,height 33px,right one very long rectangle, draw from top to bottom from px0 to px480 width 34px,height 1px, sorry for virtual code but you know what I means.

My previous game is written in SurfaceView, worked on 320x480, 480x800, 480x854 and 1024x768.

The picture look like work, width filled but bottom has biggest empty.

If I insert w=320; h=480; before GLUgluOrtho2D in SurfaceChanged,some object work(which not use crop by UV)

[image: image1]
http://i1105.photobucket.com/albums/h355/ch_mac/device_str5.png

The result I would like :

[image: wantedresult]
http://i1105.photobucket.com/albums/h355/ch_mac/device_str6.png

My texture drawing method :

```
public void draw(int from_x,int from_y,int w,int h,int pos_x,int pos_y)
{

          bind();
          float texW=(float)mPow2Width;  
          float texH=(float)mPow2Height;

          float minU= from_x/texW;
          float maxU = (from_x+w)/texW;        
          float minV= from_y/texH;        
          float maxV = (from_y+h)/texH;
           float verticleBuffer[] = {
               x,  y,
             x+w,  y,
               x, y+h,
             x+w, y+h,
           };
           float coordBuffer[] = {
            minU, minV,
            maxU, minV,
            minU, maxV,
            maxU, maxV, 
    };

FloatBuffer     m_vertexBuffer;
    FloatBuffer     m_textureBuffer;
    ByteBuffer l_byteBuf;
    l_byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( verticleBuffer.length * 4 );
    l_byteBuf.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );
    m_vertexBuffer = l_byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    m_vertexBuffer.put( verticleBuffer );
    m_vertexBuffer.position( 0 );

    l_byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( coordBuffer.length * 4 );
    l_byteBuf.clear();
    l_byteBuf.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );
    m_textureBuffer = l_byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    m_textureBuffer.put( coordBuffer );
    m_textureBuffer.position( 0 );

           gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_textureBuffer);
           gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_vertexBuffer);     
           gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

}
```

SurfaceChanged :

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) 
{
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    float aspect_w=(float)h/(float)w;
    float aspect_h=(float)w/(float)h;       
    //w=320;
    //h=480;
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, w, h, 0);

gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the viewport and projection setup in the drawing handler. It's the only place where they actually make sense (like most other OpenGL operation). Doing those things somewhere else is a bookkeeping nightmare and gains no performance.

---

#### EDIT: Another issue:

```
float verticleBuffer[] = {
           x,  y,
         x+w,  y,
           x, y+h,
         x+w, y+h,
       };
float coordBuffer[] = {
        minU, minV,
        maxU, minV,
        minU, maxV,
        maxU, maxV, 
}
```

Are you sure that coordBuffer is right? To me it looks like the last two lines are swappned, i.e. that one made more sense:

```
float coordBuffer[] = {
        minU, minV,
        maxU, minV,
        maxU, maxV,
        minU, maxV, 
}
```

Comment: @ohdroid: The code in it, yes. Technically those are all drawing commands, specifically drawing setup commands. It's not uncommon to switch projection parameters and viewport several times rendering a single frame. And finally then one must do those kind of things in the drawing function anyway.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. but I think that can improvement drawing performance, but my issue still exist, do you have meet these strange issue ? I have search somedata from google say might aspect ratio wrong, cause drawing object is not drawing correct.

Comment: please open the image above name device_str5.png you can see the issue, and device_str6.png is what I want..

Comment: I try to modify coordBuffer code to yours but image are inclined. BTW, what is your GLU.gluOrtho2D parameter on 480x854 device?

Comment: @ohdroid: I don't use GLU anymore. Franky I never understood why there's a gluOrtho2D, with OpenGL offering glOrtho. Just call gl.glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, -1, 1).

Comment: Finally I didn't adjust glOrtho parameter, just add anyDesinty="false" in AndroidManifest.xml and texture parameter